# Div convert to image or base64 with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I need to convert my div in image or base64 using JS.

I found the html2canvas library on the Internet that performs this procedure, but always displays the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

When I add the element "canvas" it shows no error, but does not generate the base64 and neither image

I did the code with and without the canvas, Find the code below.

With Canvas

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var map = document.getElementById("mapa");

  canvas.appendChild(map);

  html2canvas(canvas, { 
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log("Imagem - dataurl",dataUrl);
    var encodedPng = dataUrl.substr(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1, dataUrl.length);
    var decodedPng = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);
  }});
```

Without Canvas

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mapa");
  html2canvas(canvas, { 
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log("Imagem - dataurl",dataUrl);
    var encodedPng = dataUrl.substr(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1, dataUrl.length);
    var decodedPng = Base64Binary.decode(encodedPng);
  }});
```

I appreciate any help, as it already does not know what to do to accomplish this task!

Tks,

Comment: From what I have read, this seems like a CORS issue. Are you accessing this off of your local file system? If so, try making a test server on your own computer. I think it has to do with accessing local files. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported

Comment: It contains images outside of your domain, thus the error.

Comment: I'm actually taking the picture from google, so this causing the error. 

I'll have to change how I look the picture, put it locally. 

Thank you very much,