# Save canvas as png locally with javascript with Cross doimain

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, openlayers-3

I want to save an image of the canvas tag, but when i try create an image from the canvas it tells me "SecurityError: The operation is insecure", which i believe is problems with the canvas coming from another domain than what im on. This canvas is a map which is generated with openlayers3.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-unselectable')[0];
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var window = window.open();
window.document.write('<img src='+dataURL+'/>');
```

I've also tried

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
saveAs(blob, 'map.png')
}
```

Is there an easy work around so the canvas is not tainted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canvas.toDataURL() Security Error The operation is insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753754/canvas-todataurl-security-error-the-operation-is-insecure)

Answer (score 0):

You tried write in new browser window from another window this is impossible without https protocol or localhost. But you can create new img in currently window.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-unselectable')[0];
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var img = new Image();
img.width = 1000;
img.height = 1000;
img.src = dataURL;
img.onload = function () {
  document.body.append(img);
}
```

Comment: Can't run `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` cause the canvas is tainted

Comment: Try swap `var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-unselectable')[0];
` on `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_id');`

Comment: The canvas tag is generated by openlayers 3.