# Convert canvas to base64 error

Tags: javascript

Result convert is null png image, pls help me

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://advs.jp/cp/barcode/code128.cgi?nt=1&height=80&c=Z103B5-190-311378&.png';
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL().replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
    localStorage.setItem("img", dataurl);
 $('#bannerImg').attr('src', dataurl);
```

```html
  <img id="bannerImg" src="" alt="Banner Image" width="100%" height="200px" alt="Embbed Image"/>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include everything (drawing to canvas + reading from it + setting this elsewhere) in the `onload` event of the image. It doesn't work on this snippet (the call to `toDataURL`) due to a cross-domain issue, but it shall work on your website.

[An explanation of why it doesn't work here the call to `toDataURL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22716873/214898)

```js
var imgCanvas = function() {     
    var img = new Image();
    //Wait for image to load before doing something with content
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
        //Set canvas size to fit the image
        canvas.style.height = img.height + 'px';
        canvas.style.width = img.width + 'px';
      
        //Draw the image in canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
      
        //Get a dataurl representation of the image where the image itself is in BASE64
        var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
      
        //Store it in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("img", dataurl);  
      
        //Show image from localStorage
        //Need jQuery to use this line instead of next one : $('#bannerImg').attr('src', localStorage.getItem("img")); 
        document.getElementById('bannerImg').setAttribute('src', localStorage.getItem("img"));
    };
    img.src = 'http://advs.jp/cp/barcode/code128.cgi?nt=1&height=80&c=Z103B5-190-311378&.png';
};

imgCanvas();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Canvas:<br>
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>

<br><br>

Image from dataurl:<br>
<img id='bannerImg'>
```

Comment: That is what you get with `$('#bannerImg').attr('src', dataurl); `

Comment: Please help me export base64 image

Comment: What do you mean by export ? To where ? Is the `dataurl` variable having something now ? (Answer all please)

Comment: i have a image URL, and i want to convert to base64 image and store on local storerage.

Comment: I commented the code all over. I'm not sure I could me more clearer than that. I tested it on my local server and it works fine using an image coming from my local server.

Comment: how to convert from canvas to base64 image, pls help me Mr/Mss Master DJon

Comment: Did you look at the content of `dataurl` variable ?

Comment: Then, didn't you see the BASE64 content there ?

Comment: yes i want to show base64 content at id="bannerImg"

Comment: So, you do not want to show the image but the BASE64 string ? Because now it set the image from a BASE64 data url.

Comment: base64 string will fill into src <img id="bannerImg" src="" alt="Banner Image"> and show base64 image

Comment: Well, it is exactly doing that. If it doesn't work, look at the web development tools of your browser. You will probably see a cross-domain issue and this explanation is in the link I put in the answer. Not sure I can do more.

Comment: Is "advs.jp" your domain ?

Comment: So add the code I gave somewhere accessible for me and give me the URL.

Comment: my company send me a image url and request convert to base 64 , i dont know somewhere accessible...

Comment: Well the URL for the image you gave is accessible. Can't you add an HTML page on this domain and give me the URL ?

Comment: i can't add anything... you can draw image and store in local storerage, then convert to base64 and show it ?

Comment: All the answers are here. Take a pause and look carefully. Sorry, I would like to do more, but I doesn't have anything else to give you a hand.

Comment: I think you shall at least accept one of the answer, as both are correct (virtually the same).

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('bannerImg').setAttribute('src', dataurl);` instead.

```
var showImage = function() {     
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  
        var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
        localStorage.setItem("img", dataurl);  
        document.getElementById('bannerImg').setAttribute('src', dataurl); 
    };
    img.src = 'http://advs.jp/cp/barcode/code128.cgi?nt=1&height=80&c=Z103B5-190-311378&.png';
};

showImage();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6152/

Comment: still null png image

Comment: i need base64 image show on id="bannerImg"..thank you

Comment: Updated to use `document.getElementById('bannerImg').setAttribute( 'src', dataurl);` instead.

Comment: There is still a cross-domain issue. See the link I put in my answer.

Comment: Image from origin 'http://advs.jp' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I mentioned the snippet wouldn't work here, but I tested on my local server to ensure (even I already did that, but you know memory). And it works fine if image is coming from local.