# How to convert image into base64 and store it in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How can i convert selected image into base64 and then save it in the local Storage for later use.

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
    image.addEventListener('change', function() {
    //How to 
    });
```

Comment: I would use the usual methods for conversion to base64, and setting a vlaue in localStorage

Comment: Why don't just save the path to `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this post, they explain exactly what you need :
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/

But instead of base64 encoding, they extract the image data using canvas + toDataUrl() which convert the image data from Blob to Data URL.

Be careful with images loaded from external websites, the crossOrigin policy may throw a Security error. (See [22710627](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported))

```
// Get a reference to the image element
var elephant = document.getElementById("elephant");

// Take action when the image has loaded
elephant.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture
    imgCanvas.width = elephant.width;
    imgCanvas.height = elephant.height;

    // Draw image into canvas element
    imgContext.drawImage(elephant, 0, 0, elephant.width, elephant.height);

    // Get canvas contents as a data URL
    var imgAsDataURL = imgCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    // Save image into localStorage
    try {
        localStorage.setItem("elephant", imgAsDataURL);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
    }
}, false);
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Make sure the image is fully loaded before injecting it the canvas :)

Answer (score 0):

[How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

You can use the HTML5  for it:

Create a canvas, load your image into it and then use toDataURL() to get the base64 representation (actually, it's a data: URL but it contains the base64-encoded image).

Then save this data to lcoalStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('imgBase64', this.yourVariable);
```