# jquery.qrcode.js render to img with logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I used jquery.qrcode.js to generate a qrcode image with logo .
There has a logo on generated `<canvas>` , but when I used `toDataURL` to render to `<img />` , logo was disappeared . 
How can I correct to render a qrcode image with logo to `<img />` ?
This is my code .

```
$('#qrcode').qrcode({
    render: 'canvas',
    text: QRCODE,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    background: "#ffffff",
    foreground: "#000000",
    src: 'https://wx.style999.com/static/user/img/favicon.ico'
})
$('#qrcode > img').attr('src', $('#qrcode > canvas')[0].toDataURL('image/png'))
```

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logo does not appear because you export the data URL before the final canvas is created. Adding a logo to the QR code is an async process. Setting `src` of the image after the final canvas is created should fix the problem.

For example, using `setTimeout` (though it is not a good practice and I don't know if this library provides you with some callbacks).

However, since the logo is from the internet and not your domain, you may face a `Tainted canvases may not be exported` problem.

You can also read this. [Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)