# Get dataUrl from stage in react-konva

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I rendered konva stage with 2 images overlapping each other. Now, I am trying to export the overlapped image from the stage and canvas.
I tried to get `const dataURL = this.stageNode.getStage().toDataURL();`
and added stageNode like

```
 <Stage ref={node => {
      this.stageNode = node;
    }}>
```

But still I am not able to access base64 string from stage.
[A trail with react kova image sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y4oooxqlj)

PS:This is related to https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/305 to some extent

Comment: Do you have any errors? Can you make an online demo of what you are trying?

Comment: getting a warning:  Konva warning: Unable to get data URL. Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
Added my code at https://codesandbox.io/s/zr3r3lr3l4

Comment: You have a blank URL, because you have CORS issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using images from same domain solves the issue which was faced, could not implement the fix in online demo. Thanks @lavrton for prompt reply