# Tainted canvases may not be exported error on chrome when i reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, todataurl

I am making paint like web application using canvas, it is working properly on Firefox but when I reload the page on chrome and use .ToDataURL function it gives me an error of  Tainted canvases may not be exported

```
canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    widthOfCanvas = canvas.width;
    highOfCanvas = canvas.height;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src='https://scontent.fkhi9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/53169476_2381573508543072_5059610343865581568_n.png?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ht=scontent.fkhi9-1.fna&oh=bad33f4d78d743ed41c3455dcde6eeae&oe=5CE3CD71';
    image.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    console.log(image.onload)
    image.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0 ,widthOfCanvas,highOfCanvas);             
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported