# How to load URL-picture into canvas, failed to execute toDataURL

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to load a png-image into a canvas get the base64-string from it.

This is my code:

```
pic2b64: function () {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/dog/dog_PNG50346.png";

    img.addEventListener('load', e => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    })

},
```

When I want to execute my code, I get the following error in the browser:

> Failed to execute `'toDataURL'` on `'HTMLCanvasElement'`: Tainted canvases may not be exported.

(programmed in javascript, executed in browser)

Comment: Please take a look at this SO question: [Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

Comment: I tried all this, but nothing help me. Maybe its a problem with my code?

Comment: I've tested your code in Codepen and it works for me. Please take a look: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/f941bfd65075fac9eb5194e69e187d5d