# download button script in javascript codeigniter not working

Tags: javascript, html, image, codeigniter, download

there is an image on my webpage, i have given user option to edit the content on the image and download the image using javascript in codeigniter. the following is the download button code:

```html
<div id="chumma" class="col-md-12">

 <button id="download" type="submit" onclick="download_image()"  name="button" value="Download" class="btn btn-primary" >Download</button>


</div>


function download_image(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
  image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = "<?php echo $val['title']; ?>.png";
  link.href = image;
    link.click();
}
```

but this is not downloading the image, instead its just reloading the page, can anyone please tell me what is wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: Is this your exact code, because there are no `<script>` tag.

Comment: @jcubic script tag is there, i just posted the download button code from my whole code

Comment: @jcubic i just want to download the image on the left side of this button using this script,

Comment: I think the issue is that you need to insert the a tag into the body before the click otherwise it will not trigger native download.

Comment: @jcubic where excactly, cn you please tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert the link into DOM, before clicking, it may be required to trigger native download.

```
function download_image(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
  image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = "<?php echo $val['title']; ?>.png";
  link.href = image;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  setTimeout(() => link.remove(), 0); // setTimeout just in case
}
```

if there is a problem that link is visible for a split of second you can hide the link with CSS.

**EDIT**: didn't notice the submit button, if you want to do action in JavaScript don't use submit button because that will send http request to the server (submit the form). If you want to do action in JavaScript use `<button type="button">` that will also work when inside the form (it will not submit).

Comment: bro i tried this, again its simply reloading the page

Comment: should i add a tag near this button,   <button id="download" type="submit" onclick="download_image()"  name="button" value="Download" class="btn btn-primary" >Download</button>

Comment: @zubairnazer sorry I didn't notice the submit button, don't use submit button if you want to do action in JavaScript because you will need to prevent default action which is sending the form (http request that look like page refresh). Use normal button and don't use `<form>` tag, if you need  form tag use `<button type="button">` so it will not submit the form.

Comment: bro, am getting the error "uncaught dom excption: failed to execute todataurl on htmlcanvas element, tainted canvas may not be exported

Comment: @zubairnazer then you have another not related error, you should look it up if you don't find information about in Google or on StackOverflow, please ask question about this error.

Comment: @zubairnazer and just so you don't need to search the error, which you should always before asking the question, here is first entry in SO and Google [Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710627/387194)