# How can I load an image bytes from the HTML page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

In a project I am currently developing, I need to load the content of an image file located in the same directory as the `index.html` page and the `app.js` script file (It is a tiny project, so everything is in the same directory). I did that easily with the Fetch API :

```
var imageBytes
fetch('image.png')
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(function(blob) {
        blob.arrayBuffer().then(function (bytes) {
            imageBytes = bytes
        })
    })
```

It works when my webpage is accessed with a web server. However, I'd like my page to work when it is loaded by clicking the `index.html` file and using it locally. I understand it is for security reasons, as my browser tries to access a the image with a `file://` request, which is blocked. However, my file *is* part of the website, it is not like if I tried to load a random file in the user filesystem.

I could ask the user to select the image with the `<input type="file">` form. But one other thing that could, maybe, work would be to add the image in my HTML page with a standard `<img src="image.png" id="myImage">` tag, and load its bytes in JS from there. However, I have no idea of how to do that. I tried `getElementById('myImage')` but what I get does not seem to contain the image itself, only its attributes. Is there a way to get the content of one of the images in my HTML page in JavaScript ?

Comment: You can try with `canvas` and `toDataURL()` but likely that this will be forbidden too - https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710627/863110