# I am trying to get image from an ip camera in php and javascript using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, ip, ip-camera

it captures the image and when I try to use canva.toDataURL() it does not give us an image and throws the exception on the console

> (index):45 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
> 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

```
 function shoot() { 
 var video = document.getElementById(videoId);
 var output = document.getElementById('output'); 
 var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor); canvas.onclick = function(){ 
 window.open(this.toDataURL()); alert(this.toDataURL()) }; 
 snapshots.unshift(canvas);
 output.innerHTML = ''; 
 for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
 output.appendChild(snapshots[i]); 
 }
```

I think problem in this onclick function

Comment: I am surprised that there was a tag named [ip-camera]

Comment: Because I am trying integrate an Ip-Camera and capturing screenshot from it. Sorry if it bothered you

Comment: Have you considered any of the answers given to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported

Comment: gonna check this

Comment: hey @Blindman67 this did not work for me

Comment: If nothing on that page helped then sorry, as the error indicates  "Tainted canvases may not be exported." There is nothing you can do to change that.

Comment: okay @Blindman67