# How can I solve the "Tainted canvas" error caused by html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, screenshot, html2canvas

I am creating a web application, and I want it to have a feature that allows the user to download screenshots of the page.
I tried to use a library called `html2canvas`, and I had written the code as it said on the tutorial, but it returned an error: 
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported`.

Here's the code that I have written to use html2canvas :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="Display"></div>
```

```js
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#Display")).then(canvas => {
   const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
   downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   downloadLink.click()
});
```

And this is the library's source code : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js

Could anyone solve this problem?

Comment: [Maybe a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported).

Comment: I tried them but unfortunately, I could not solve the problem.