# How fix DOMException capacitor android?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, capacitor

I migrate my cordova-angular project to capacitor, and i am getting an error with the following code.

```
public async saveBlobFromMobile(blob: any, fileName: string, mimeType: string = 'image/jpeg') {
    console.log('saveBlobFromMobile():',  mimeType);
    write_blob({
      path: fileName,
      blob: blob,
      directory: Directory.Documents,
      on_fallback(error) {
        console.error(error);
        this.alert.presentToast('Ошибка записи файла', 'danger');
      }
    })
    // this.isFileLoading = false;
    // this.alert.presentToast('Файл сохранен в папке "Документы" (Document)');
  }
```

at this code i have error

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
    at CameraPage.takeScreenshot (:997:32)
    at CameraPage_div_20_Template_ion_button_click_4_listener (:320:303)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (:82745:16)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (:82783:22)
    at HostElement.<anonymous> (:106548:34)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (:2750:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (:93310:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (:2749:60)
    at Zone.runTask (:2522:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://localhost/polyfills.js:2831:34) {stack: <accessor>, code: 18, name: 'SecurityError', message: 'Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvas…ment': Tainted canvases may not be exported.'}
```

What wrong? On web version? i havent any problems

```
[info] Found 3 Capacitor plugins for android:
       @capacitor-community/barcode-scanner@4.0.1
       @capacitor/filesystem@5.1.3
       capacitor-blob-writer@1.1.14
[info] Found 13 Cordova plugins for android:
       cordova-custom-config@5.1.1
       cordova-plugin-android-permissions@1.1.5
       cordova-plugin-device@2.1.0
       cordova-plugin-file@8.0.0
       cordova-plugin-file-opener2@4.0.0
       cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics@7.0.5
       cordova-plugin-nativestorage@2.3.2
       cordova-plugin-screen-orientation@3.0.3
       cordova-plugin-statusbar@3.0.0
       cordova-sqlite-storage@6.1.0
       cordova-support-android-plugin@2.0.4
       es6-promise-plugin@4.2.2
       onesignal-cordova-plugin@3.3.1
[info] Found 5 incompatible Cordova plugins for android, skipped install:
       cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@2.0.2
       cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard@2.2.0
       cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@5.0.1
       cordova-plugin-splashscreen@6.0.2
       cordova-support-google-services@1.4.1
[info] Listing plugins for web is not possible.
angular 13 version
```

How fix this?
I try update plugin and other.

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported

Comment: my element have this tag ``` this.videoElement.nativeElement.innerHTML =
            '<video id="videoChild" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" crossorigin="anonymous"></video>';
```