# Open layers Export PDF function Issue, Printing Issue

Tags: printing, gis, openlayers, geospatial, wms

I have OSM basemap and WMS layers loaded from Geoserver(PostGIS) when attempting to print using **ol.exporttopdf.js** extension, only the base map is getting exported while the layers are not being plotted

[image]

here the print code block:

```
const dims = {
    a0: [1189, 841],
    a1: [841, 594],
    a2: [594, 420],
    a3: [420, 297],
    a4: [297, 210],
    a5: [210, 148],
  };
  
  const exportButton = document.getElementById('export-pdf');
  
  exportButton.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function () {
      exportButton.disabled = true;
      document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';
  
      const format = document.getElementById('format').value;
      const resolution = document.getElementById('resolution').value;
      const dim = dims[format];
      const width = Math.round((dim[0] * resolution) / 25.4);
      const height = Math.round((dim[1] * resolution) / 25.4);
      const size = map.getSize();
      const viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  
      map.once('rendercomplete', function () {
        const mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        mapCanvas.width = width;
        mapCanvas.height = height;
        const mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(
          document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'),
          function (canvas) {
            if (canvas.width > 0) {
              const opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;
              mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
              const transform = canvas.style.transform;
              // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
              const matrix = transform
                .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1]
                .split(',')
                .map(Number);
              // Apply the transform to the export map context
              CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
                mapContext,
                matrix
              );
              mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
            }
          }
        );
        mapContext.globalAlpha = 1;
        mapContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);


        const pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
        pdf.addImage(
          mapCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'),
          'JPEG',
          0,
          0,
          dim[0],
          dim[1]
        );
        pdf.save('map.pdf');
        // Reset original map size
        map.setSize(size);
        map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution);
        exportButton.disabled = false;
        document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
      });
  
      // Set print size
      const printSize = [width, height];
      map.setSize(printSize);
      const scaling = Math.min(width / size[0], height / size[1]);
      map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution / scaling);
    },
    false
  );
```

I encountered an issue with the print function in OpenLayers. I can successfully print the base map within the specified extent. However, when attempting to load a layer from GeoServer, it takes an extended period, and consequently, exporting the map to PDF becomes infeasible. Is there a specific procedure for obtaining the exported map? I am utilizing OpenLayers, JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

Console error i'm getting:

[image]

Comment: To access the canvas you must specify `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` on any sources which do not default to that.

Comment: @Mike is correct for more reference you can visit this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22716873/3893124)