# html2canvas: Unable to Capture Screenshots with Other-Origin Images

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I'm encountering issues capturing a screenshot of a current webpage using html2canvas when the page includes images from other origins. Despite enabling CORS headers on my server with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, I'm still receiving the error message "Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
    type: 'view'
}).then(function (canvas) {
     var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
});
```

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it to successfully capture screenshots including images from other origins?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is likely due to the security restrictions related to cross-origin content. Even with CORS headers, the browser may still prevent capturing images from other origins to maintain security.

One workaround is to proxy the images through your server, so they are served from the same origin as your HTML2Canvas script.

See also [Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

Comment: how can I set proxy then images of other website through our server? Can yo provide some hint? I am also facing same issue as given in question.